# Extracting city, latitude and longitude in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geocoding, geopy

I have an address column that contains the full location of a place e.g (King Saud Road, Al Khobar 31952 Saudi Arabia). I want to extract the city in new column as well as the latitude and longitude point in another new column.

I am following the below approach to pass all values in address column to the function, but it's not working, any ideas?

[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzttM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="StackOverFlow", timeout=3)
df = pd.DataFrame({'locations': ['King Saud Road, Al Khobar 31952 Saudi Arabia',
                                 '123 Main Street, Los Angeles, CA 90034, USA']})
df['location_info'] = df.locations.apply(lambda x: geolocator.geocode(x, addressdetails=True, language='en'))
df['latitude'] = df.location_info.apply(lambda x: x.raw['lat'])
df['longitude'] = df.location_info.apply(lambda x: x.raw['lon'])
df['city'] = df.location_info.apply(lambda x: x.raw["address"]['city'])
df = df.drop(['location_info'], axis=1)
```

Comment: Well, I'm trying to pass the address column values instead of writing each value one by on as the following code:

1- locations_data = df.location.to_list().............
2- df = pd.DataFrame({'locations': locations_data})

Comment: I'm getting this error as well (GeocoderQueryError: Non-successful status code 414) ...... I have 1900 item in my 'locations' list

Comment: Creation of new dataframe is not strictly necesaary, you may still use your existing dataframe named as "df".The 414 status code is usually reserved for **Request URI Too Large**. It seems that one of your locations are exceeding the length of Nominatim willing to handle. You might consider to eliminate or fix that one. On the top of that, I would suggest you to go through the GeoPy documentiaion to set correct useragent and query intervals. [GeoPy Documentation](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html#Nominatim)

Comment: I got AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'raw' when running ... df['latitude'] = df.location_info.apply(lambda x: x.raw['lat'])
df['longitude'] = df.location_info.apply(lambda x: x.raw['lon'])
df['city'] = df.location_info.apply(lambda x: x.raw["address"]['city'])

Comment: Clearly, you have got some 'None' type returns in your location column. Try to escape them.